# How to pass object on modal view's dismissal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm presenting a VC modally, then I dismiss it when a cell is selected along with call a method from the original VC.

The problem now is that `nav` and `routineTableViewController` NSLog as null.
How I present the model VC:

```
NSString *selectedRow = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row]objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
UINavigationController *nav = self.parentViewController.navigationController;
RoutineDayTableViewController *routineDayTableViewController = (RoutineDayTableViewController *) [nav topViewController];
routineDayTableViewController.muscleURL = self.muscleURL;
[routineDayTableViewController addExercise];
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hierarchy of VC: RoutineDayTableViewController -> presents Modally MusclesTableViewController, then pushes to child table view, which dismisses back to RoutineDayTableViewController.

Edit:

```
-(void)addExercise
{       
    PFObject *exerciseInRoutine = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"exerciseInRoutine"];
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.selectedExercise forKey:@"name"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.muscleName forKey:@"muscle"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.muscleURL forKey:@"picture"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my reply here: [How to save nsdictionary of a subview to a mainview based off tableviewcell selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922305/how-to-save-nsdictionary-of-a-subview-to-a-mainview-based-off-tableviewcell-sele/7948912#7948912)

The ideal solution is to create a **protocol** and **use a delegate** to pass information backwards in your view controller hierarchy. This avoids the tight coupling which is happening in your example when you link back to `self.parentViewController.navigationController`.  What happens if the parent view controller changes in the future or you want to resuse the selection controller elsewhere in the app? The new view controller that is the parent could be an instance of a class other than `RoutineDayTableViewController` and may not have a `exerciseURL` property.

For this specific example, I would do something like the following:

Add the protocol definition inside **SpecificExerciseTableViewController.h**

```
@class SpecificExerciseTableViewController;

@protocol SpecificExerciseTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)specificExerciseTableViewController:(SpecificExerciseTableViewController *)specificExerciseTableViewController didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:(NSURL *)exerciseURL;
@end
```

Add a property inside **MuscleTableViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

Add a property inside **SpecificExerciseTableViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SpecificExerciseTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Inside **RoutineDayTableViewController.h**

```
#import "SpecificExerciseTableViewController.h"

@interface RoutineDayTableViewController <SpecificExerciseTableViewControllerDelegate>
```

Inside **RoutineDayTableViewController.m** when allocating a `MusclesTableViewController` instance:

```
MuscleTableViewController *muscleTableViewController = [[MuscleTableViewController alloc] init];
muscleTableViewController.delegate = self;
```

Inside **MuscleTableViewController.m** when allocating a `SpecificExerciseTableViewController` instance:

```
SpecificExerciseTableViewController *specificExerciseTableViewController = [[SpecificExerciseTableViewController alloc] init];
specificExerciseTableViewController.delegate = self.delegate;
```

Inside **SpecificExerciseTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(specificExerciseTableViewController:didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:)])
    {
        NSURL *selectedExerciseURL = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
        [self.delegate specificExerciseTableViewController:self didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:selectedExerciseURL];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Finally, in your **RoutineDayTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)specificExerciseTableViewController:(SpecificExerciseTableViewController *)specificExerciseTableViewController didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:(NSURL *)exerciseURL;
{
    [self addExercise];
}
```

For an example of this in practice in a video see:

**00:30:00** min mark in [WWDC 2011 Video - Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=309)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example tailored to your situation.

Comment: I'm getting error that RoutineDayTableViewController.h cannot find the declaration protocall. I put the declaration before the interface in MuscleTableViewController right?

Comment: Yes, also be sure you put `#import "MusclesTableViewController.h"` inside `RoutineDayTableViewController.h` because `MusclesTableViewController.h` is where the protocol is defined.

Comment: I did that but it still isn't working. I'm now getting an error `expected a type` when I do @protocal declaration.

Comment: Forward-declare `@class MusclesTableViewController;` before the @protocol since it is before @interface.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  But I think you did it backwards.  I want to select the cell in MuscleTableVC, which should dismiss itself, and send the data to RoutineDayTableVC.

Comment: That is what this is doing.  When a row is selected inside the `MusclesTableViewController` instance, it sends a message back to it's delegate (`RoutineDayTableViewController`) called `-musclesTableViewController:didSelectExerciseWithMuscleURL:` passing the URL that was selected in MusclesTableViewController. I've updated the answer with the modal view controller dismissal in the correct place.

Comment: Ok, one last thing.  I'm selecting the row from `MuscleTableVC's` child table VC, which is called `SpecificExerciseTableViewController`.  So do I need to modify the code?  Because it has to travel two layers up.

Comment: Yes, to go deeper you would need to create a similar protocol such as **SpecificExerciseTableViewControllerDelegate** with a `-specificExerciseTableViewController:didSelectSpecificExercise:` method. This could send the data back to the MuscleTableViewController. If only `RoutineDayTableViewController` needed the selection data from SpecificExerciseTableViewControllerDelegate, you could make `RoutineDayTableViewController` adopt the <MusclesTableViewControllerDelegate> protocol and set `RoutineDayTableViewController`'s delegate to the `SpecificExerciseTableViewController` instance.

Comment: I only need `RoutineDayTableViewController` to get the selection data from `SpecificExerciseTableViewController`.  Can I therefore remove all code related to `MusclesTableViewController`?

Comment: You can then replace all instances of `MusclesTableViewController` with `SpecificExerciseTableViewController` and change the method names accordingly and it will work like you want, passing data from `SpecificExerciseTableViewController` to `RoutineDayTableViewController`. The one catch is that you need to pass the pointer to `RoutineDayTableViewController` to `MusclesTableViewController` then to `SpecificExerciseTableViewController`. So you will want to put delegate properties on both classes, and just simply assign that variable up the chain as you instantiate new view controllers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I tried that but I'm getting a bit lost in the process because its 3 separate classes.  If you get a chance, can you update your answer accordingly? Then I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.  With a multiple view controller depth scenario the `MuscleTableViewController` now has a `delegate` property that is used pass along the pointer to the instance of RoutineDayTableViewController -> MuscleTableViewController -> SpecificExerciseTableViewController.

Comment: Thanks.  Everything works except `[routineDayTableViewController addExercise];`.  It is not recognizing `routineDayTableViewController` in 'RoutineDayTableViewController.m'.  Should it just be `self`?

Comment: One absolutely last thing.  Do the names of objects in the delegate method have to match the delegate class's properties?  I want the delegate method to pass the following objects with these names: `self.selectedExercise, self.muscleName, self.muscleURL`.  Those are the names of the properties in `RoutineDayTableViewController`.  I have the same named properties in `SpecificExerciseTableViewController`.

Comment: The property names in the class instances do not need to match between classes. You can change the delegate method prototype to include any additional parameters you want, just make sure you update the code everywhere that method prototype is used, including the @selector() check.

E.g.  `- (void)specificExerciseTableViewController:(SpecificExerciseTableViewController *)specificExerciseTableViewController didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:(NSURL *)exerciseURL muscleName:(NSString *)muscleName muscleURL:(NSURL *)muscleURL;` then update the rest of the code to reflect the new method name.

Comment: Hi Andrew, everyhting is working fine except the app crashes when `addExercise` is called.  I think the delegate is fine, but the values aren't getting passed because they're nil when I log them in the `addExercise` method. I'm adding method to the question.