# Notify parent class when an error occur

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing an iOS 4 application.

I have a ViewController that contains another class. In this class, I use CoreLocation to track GPS and heading.

I want to notify ViewController that there is an error on GPS tracking with this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I want to check if user has disable Location tracking and show a AlertView, but I only can do that on a viewController.

How can I notify ViewController when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either use a notification or delegation.  In this case, delegation is a better fit.  See my answers to and you should be able to adapt them accordingly for your case.

- [How to save nsdictionary of a subview to a mainview based off tableviewcell selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922305/how-to-save-nsdictionary-of-a-subview-to-a-mainview-based-off-tableviewcell-sele/7948912#7948912)
- [How to pass object on modal view's dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962519/how-to-pass-object-on-modal-views-dismissal/7962637#7962637)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass your UIViewController and add the method needed to receive a specific error notification from your view.