# Move from UITableviewcell to a ViewController and back using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have a viewcontroller with multiple tableviewcells in it. I want move from one of the tableviewcell to another viewcontroller using storyboard. I have a navigation controller for viewcontroller. I didn't really find a way to solve this.

Comment: Do you mean move from a VC to another VC by tap a UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Yes when I select cell it should move to a VC

Comment: Implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate. When you tap a cell, control will comes into this method. Write the computation logic there and navigate to the respective view controller.

Comment: That the code I want  I couldn't use navigationcontroller because its a uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate, then some logic for move to another view controller.

```
@interface ViewController()<UITableViewDelegate>

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AnotherViewControllerClass *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardNameOfAnotherViewController" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewControllerIdentifier"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use navigationcontroller                                                                         " Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type UITableViewCell"

Comment: You should implement this in your UITableViewController subclass and not in your UITableViewCell (custom).

Comment: My Tableview is inside Viewcontroller and I have done inside viewcontroller

Comment: then you should implement this inside viewcontroller, not inside uitableviewcell

Comment: this function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  called when you tap a cell, right? and the problem is you couldn't use navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do with storyBoard then you can use Segue to jump from one tableview cell to another ViewController what you have to do is 
1).  right click and drag from your table view cell to your desired view Controller and then release it you would see a pop up select "show"
2). click the segue and go to identity inspector and name the segue identifier as you wish 
3).then you have to just write a method prepareFor segue methodand in that write if statement like this

```
if (segue.identifier == "your identifier Name")
{
  //`enter code here`write your logic of pushing the viewcontroller  
}
```

the above code for if is in swift and you can repeat the steps for your all multiple tableviewcell with diffrent identifier name

if not using storyboard then use this method

```
if (indexpath.row == 0)
{
  //use the push viewcontroller code here 
}
```

for each index path you can check and push diffrent viewcontrollers

Comment: I don't want to go for segue

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

- Open Storyboard and select your initial view controller
- Select editor from top bar menu in your Xcode
- Select Embed in and choose UINavigationController

And run your code again...

Comment: I got a code using nsnotificationcenter, In which I could solve the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395343/how-to-pass-the-selected-data-back-to-previous-view-controller